# Parallel finite-difference calculation in OpenMDAO executes each point in each process

Tags: openmdao

I am trying to set up a problem in OpenMDAO and would like to make use of parallel finite difference computations. However, when I call `compute_totals()` each MPI process actually computes all the perturbed points.

I have made a minimal example that demonstrates the problem. Consider the simple case of a model which can be represented by a matrix multiplication. The Jacobian of this model is simply the matrix of the model. See the code below:

```
import numpy as np
import time

from openmdao.api import ExplicitComponent, Problem, IndepVarComp, Group
from openmdao.utils.mpi import MPI

rank = 0 if not MPI else MPI.COMM_WORLD.rank

class MatMultComp(ExplicitComponent):
    def __init__(self, matrix, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.matrix = matrix

    def setup(self):
        self.add_input('x', val=np.ones(self.matrix.shape[1])))
        self.add_output('y', val=np.ones(self.matrix.shape[0])))

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs, **kwargs):
        outputs['y'] = self.matrix.dot(inputs['x'])
        print('{} :: x = {}'.format(rank, np.array_str(inputs['x'])))


class Model(Group):
    def setup(self):
        matrix = np.arange(25, dtype=float).reshape(5, 5)
        self.add_subsystem('ivc', IndepVarComp('x', np.ones(matrix.shape[1])), promotes=['*'])
        self.add_subsystem('mat', MatMultComp(matrix), promotes=['*'])
        self.approx_totals(step=0.1)
        self.num_par_fd = matrix.shape[1]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Problem()
    p.model = Model()
    p.setup()
    p.run_model()

    t0 = time.time()
    jac = p.compute_totals(of=['y'], wrt=['x'], return_format='array')
    dt = time.time() - t0

    if rank == 0:
        print('Took {:2.3f} seconds.'.format(dt))
        print('J = ')
        print(np.array_str(jac, precision=0))
```

When I run this code without MPI, I get the following output:

```
0 :: x = [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
0 :: x = [1.1 1.  1.  1.  1. ]
0 :: x = [1.  1.1 1.  1.  1. ]
0 :: x = [1.  1.  1.1 1.  1. ]
0 :: x = [1.  1.  1.  1.1 1. ]
0 :: x = [1.  1.  1.  1.  1.1]
Took 5.008 seconds.
J = 
[[ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.]
 [ 5.  6.  7.  8.  9.]
 [10. 11. 12. 13. 14.]
 [15. 16. 17. 18. 19.]
 [20. 21. 22. 23. 24.]]
```

This is the correct result, and takes about 5 seconds, as expected. Now, when I run this with MPI, using 5 processes, with the command `mpirun -np 5 python matmult.py`, I get the following output:

```
0 :: x = [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
1 :: x = [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
2 :: x = [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
3 :: x = [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
4 :: x = [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
0 :: x = [1.001 1.    1.    1.    1.   ]
1 :: x = [1.001 1.    1.    1.    1.   ]
2 :: x = [1.001 1.    1.    1.    1.   ]
3 :: x = [1.001 1.    1.    1.    1.   ]
4 :: x = [1.001 1.    1.    1.    1.   ]
3 :: x = [1.    1.001 1.    1.    1.   ]
0 :: x = [1.    1.001 1.    1.    1.   ]
1 :: x = [1.    1.001 1.    1.    1.   ]
2 :: x = [1.    1.001 1.    1.    1.   ]
4 :: x = [1.    1.001 1.    1.    1.   ]
2 :: x = [1.    1.    1.001 1.    1.   ]
3 :: x = [1.    1.    1.001 1.    1.   ]
0 :: x = [1.    1.    1.001 1.    1.   ]
1 :: x = [1.    1.    1.001 1.    1.   ]
4 :: x = [1.    1.    1.001 1.    1.   ]
1 :: x = [1.    1.    1.    1.001 1.   ]
2 :: x = [1.    1.    1.    1.001 1.   ]
3 :: x = [1.    1.    1.    1.001 1.   ]
0 :: x = [1.    1.    1.    1.001 1.   ]
4 :: x = [1.    1.    1.    1.001 1.   ]
0 :: x = [1.    1.    1.    1.    1.001]
1 :: x = [1.    1.    1.    1.    1.001]
2 :: x = [1.    1.    1.    1.    1.001]
3 :: x = [1.    1.    1.    1.    1.001]
4 :: x = [1.    1.    1.    1.    1.001]
Took 5.072 seconds.
J = 
[[ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.]
 [ 5.  6.  7.  8.  9.]
 [10. 11. 12. 13. 14.]
 [15. 16. 17. 18. 19.]
 [20. 21. 22. 23. 24.]]
```

The final result is correct, of course. However, this defies the purpose of using MPI, because each of the 5 processes computed all the perturbed points, and the total execution takes about 5 seconds like before. I expected the following output:

```
0 :: x = [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
1 :: x = [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
2 :: x = [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
3 :: x = [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
4 :: x = [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
0 :: x = [1.1 1.  1.  1.  1. ]
1 :: x = [1.  1.1 1.  1.  1. ]
2 :: x = [1.  1.  1.1 1.  1. ]
3 :: x = [1.  1.  1.  1.1 1. ]
4 :: x = [1.  1.  1.  1.  1.1]
Took 1.000 seconds.
J = 
[[ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.]
 [ 5.  6.  7.  8.  9.]
 [10. 11. 12. 13. 14.]
 [15. 16. 17. 18. 19.]
 [20. 21. 22. 23. 24.]]
```

Note that in reality the order in which the processes finish is arbitrary, and the time it took will be a little more than 1 second.

How can I get this to work as expected? Note that I am using OpenMDAO 2.5.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few of issues here.  The first is that `num_par_fd` should typically be passed as an `__init__` arg to your Group or your Component.  Setting it in the Component or Group's `setup()` function is too late, because OpenMDAO does all of its MPI communicator splitting in the `_setup_procs` function, which happens *before* the Component/Group `setup` call.  The same timing issue applies to calling the `approx_totals` function.  It must be called prior to the Problem `setup` call.  Finally, the name of the attribute we use internally to specify the number of parallel FD computations is actually `self._num_par_fd` and not `self.num_par_fd`.  Setting of the internal `_num_par_fd` attribute isn't recommended, but if you must, you'll have to set it *before* Problem `setup` is called.

Note: this is a heavily edited version of my original answer.

Comment: This makes sense. However, I tried changing `self.num_par_fd = matrix.shape[1]` to `self._num_par_fd = matrix.shape[1]`, but I got exactly the same output. Furthermore, when I instead changed the code so I do `p.model = Model(num_par_fd=5)`, I get `RuntimeError: '': num_par_fd = 5 but FD is not active.`.